# Specific TLS version for STARTTLS in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, cryptography, starttls

How can I specify the TLS version with `tls.createSecurePair` or `crypto.createCredentials`?

I am asking b/c I want to add STARTTLS server support to this [starttls node lib](https://github.com/felixhammerl/starttls).

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need a starttls module with node v0.8+. However to specify the TLS/SSL version, you do need node v0.10+. Here's how you'd do it to force TLSv1 for example:

```
// `sock` is your tcp socket
var encryptedSock = tls.connect({
  socket: sock,
  secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method'
}, function() {
  // socket upgraded!
});
```

`secureProtocol` could also be `'SSLv3_method'` or `'SSLv2_method'`.

Comment: Does not work on the server side? node.js *is* on the server side.

Comment: wow.
1) this is not universally true, see atom-shell or node-webkit
2) i am talking about TLS server and client. you do realize, that a node instance can open a TLS port and therefore act as a server and another instance can connect to said port and act as a client.